# Windows resize event not properly detected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation menu that should stay fixed at the top of the page using the [sticky.js plugin](http://stickyjs.com/) for window-widths equal or larger than 992 px. For smaller windows, it should just go with the flow of the site. Now, as this is a responsive website, I would like to implement a dynamic window width detection when the window is resized.

The following code does not seem to correctly detect the resize event. I have to reload the page to stick / unstick the navbar at the correct width:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var currentWindow = $(window);

function checkWidth() {

    var windowSize = currentWindow.width();
    if (windowSize >= 992) {

        // Sticky.js
        $('.navbar').sticky({ 
            topSpacing: 0, 
            getWidthFrom: '.upper-header',
            responsiveWidth: true
        });

    } else {
        alert('Window is smaller');
    }
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);

});
```

Would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: `checkWidth` doesn't unstick the navbar when the window shrinks, it just displays an alert.

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6gwggb7j/

Comment: The width is detected correctly if you display it with console.log, but the navbar stays sticky at small resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unstick the navbar when the window shrinks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentWindow = $(window);
    var stuck = false; // So we only call the plugin when necessary

    function checkWidth() {

        var windowSize = currentWindow.width();
        if (windowSize >= 992 && !stuck) {

            // Sticky.js
            $('.navbar').sticky({ 
                topSpacing: 0, 
                getWidthFrom: '.upper-header',
                responsiveWidth: true
            });
            stuck = true;

        } else if (windowSize < 992 && stuck) {
            alert('Window is smaller');
            $('.navbar').unstick();
            stuck = false;
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    currentWindow.resize(checkWidth);

});
```

Comment: I overlooked that the plugin has an .unstick(). Your solution works.